# Is it possible to stop printing out in a console information after calling dhclient -6 if an address cannot be assigned to an interface?

Tags: linux, c, dhclient

When I run `dhclient -v -i <interface?>` to get IPv4 address and the address is not assigned to an interface, after some time, the command shows information that there was no offers and it stops, but dhclient still runs. When I do the same for IPv6 `dhclient -6 -v -i <interface>` the command never stops. I tried to decrease `timeout` in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` but changing this value seems not working. I need to call `system(dhclient -6 -i <interface>)` in my C application but when the address cannot be assigned, this call stops my application forever. How can I force to stop it if there is no address offers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `man 8 dhclient`, this option shall provide you the wanted behaviour:

```
-1
Try once to get a lease. One failure, exit with code 2.
```